# Align equations using \begin{cases}

Tags: equations, align, cases

I'm looking to have the beginning of the bottom equation aligned with the beginning of the top equation. Similarly, I would like to have all the "for"s aligned, so the bottom ones aligned with the top ones too. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,default,numbered,print,index]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for the inclusion of images
\usepackage{setspace} % for use of \singlespacing and \doublespacing
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\frac{p'}{\gamma \bar{p}}\Bigg|_d(x,t) \approx 
\begin{cases} 
      (P_d^+ + P_d^-R_1e^{-2\alpha(L_1 + x)})(1 + R_2e^{-2\alpha(L_2 - x)})\\ \times \dfrac{1- (R_1R_2e^{-2\alpha L})^{\lfloor (t + T)/T\rfloor}}{1-R_1R_2e^{-2\alpha L}}
      & \text{for}\enspace t \in [0,t_p]
      \\
      2P_D(R_1R_2e^{-2\alpha L})^{\lfloor (t - t_p + T)/T\rfloor}
      & \text{for}\enspace t \in ] t_p, +\infty[.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{p'}{\gamma \bar{p}}\Bigg|_i(x,t) \approx
\begin{cases} 
      P_i^+(1 + ^-R_1e^{-2\alpha(L_1 + x)}) \\ \times \dfrac{1- (R_1R_2e^{-2\alpha L})^{\lfloor (t - \tau_c + T)/T\rfloor}}{1-R_1R_2e^{-2\alpha L}}
      & \text{for}\enspace t \in [0,t_p]
      \\
      2P_I(R_1R_2e^{-2\alpha L})^{\lfloor (t - t_p - \tau_c + T)/T\rfloor}
      & \text{for}\enspace t \in ] t_p, +\infty[.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: a couple of things somewhat off-topic: (1) the page width in the output you show is larger than what's allowed in the code, or your use of `[12pt]` in the code example doesn't match the original, since the output from the example doesn't have enough space for the equation number on the first equation to fit where it's shown in the output example; and (2) the spacing between `\in` and the "open" `]` is bad -- this is a case where `\left] ... \right[` is necessary.

Comment: would you find a layout where there's an overlap of the first line with the "for" expressions acceptable?  (i understand that it's not "usual".)

Comment: hi @barbara beeton - thanks for your comments. I have fixed the space, thanks for pointing it out! Regarding the page width - it's because I'm using a thesis document class. Maybe next time I should upload the document class file along with the code? Is that doable?

Comment: if the document class is an "uncommon" one, it would help if you identify it, but in this case, setting the page width to be the same (maybe with geometry) should be sufficient if you explain what you've done.  also, for this example, most of those packages aren't necessary, so omitting them would be appreciated.

Comment: more on the matter of `]...[`.  if i remember correctly (it's been a long time), that indicates an "open interval", so maybe creating a command `\openinterval` that puts in the `\left]` and `\right[` around an argument would even make the input easier to read (if a bit longer to type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group the two `equation` environments in a single `align` and use `\mathrlap` since the first line is too long.

Note you don't have to load `array` if you load `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,default,numbered,print,index]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for the inclusion of images
\usepackage{setspace} % for use of \singlespacing and \doublespacing
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{mathtools, bm}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{2}
\renewcommand\theequation{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{39}
\begin{align}
\frac{p'}{\gamma \bar{p}}\Bigg|_d(x,t) & \approx
\begin{cases}
      (P_d^+ + P_d^-R_1e^{-2\alpha(L_1 + x)})(1 + R_2\mathrlap{e^{-2\alpha(L_2 - x)})}\\ \times \dfrac{1- (R_1R_2e^{-2\alpha L})^{\lfloor (t + T)/T\rfloor}}{1-R_1R_2e^{-2\alpha L}}
      & \text{for}\enspace t \in [0,t_p]
      \\
      2P_D(R_1R_2e^{-2\alpha L})^{\lfloor (t - t_p + T)/T\rfloor}
      & \text{for}\enspace t \in {] t_p, +\infty[}.
\end{cases} \\[1.5ex]
\frac{p'}{\gamma \bar{p}}\Bigg|_i(x,t) & \approx
\begin{cases}
      P_i^+(1 + ^-R_1e^{-2\alpha(L_1 + x)}) \\ \times \dfrac{1- (R_1R_2e^{-2\alpha L})^{\lfloor (t - \tau_c + T)/T\rfloor}}{1-R_1R_2e^{-2\alpha L}}
      & \text{for}\enspace t \in [0,t_p]
      \\
      2P_I(R_1R_2e^{-2\alpha L})^{\lfloor (t - t_p - \tau_c + T)/T\rfloor}
      & \text{for}\enspace t \in {] t_p, +\infty[}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please fix the spacing after the `\in` in the third row of each case.  my comment above says how to do that.

Comment: hi @Bernard. Thanks for your comments - the p' side is aligned but the "for" for equation 2.41 isn't aligned with the "for" for 2.40. any way of doing that too?

Comment: @jrjrjr: It's more complex (except adding some space by trial and error). I'll try to find a neater solution, but I can't guarantee.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I didn't even notice, but you're right. Not so good semantically, but an additional pair of braces does the job, and it's faster to type.

Comment: @Bernard -- i had created a test that was much the same as yours, and got a closer alignment of the "for"s.  i chose to put the `\mathrlap` just before the `R`.  then i added `\qquad\mathstrut` after the left-hand side of the last line in (2.49) and `\quad\mathstrut` after the left-hand side of the last line in (2.50).  it was pretty much pure chance that the alignment was closer, but it looked close enough that further tinkering should  be minimized.  (the `\mathstrut` is needed, otherwise the end-of-segment space is gobbled.)

Comment: Thanks so much (both of you) for your help. It worked :)